# Assigning materials to an OBJLoader model in three.js

Tags: three.js

I've imported an OBJ model with the following code:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.addEventListener('load', function (geometry) {
    object = geometry.content;
    scene.add(object);
});
loader.load('ship.obj');
```

It works fine, but whenever I try to add a material to it, it either has no effect or the model disappears. I assumed I could do it like this:

```
var ship = new THREE.Mesh(object, material);
```

But that doesn't work. does anyone know of a way to do this, or if it's even possible? I've tried using OBJMTLLoader too, but it just adds complication while still not allowing me to change the material.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

EDIT: This answer is now outdated. Instead, see the answer by @mightypile.

---

Assuming you have properly defined `material`, try this:

```
loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

    var object = event.content;

    object.traverse( function ( child ) {

        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

            child.material = material;

        }

    } );

    scene.add( object );

});
```

Comment: How can we affect the model outside of the loading routine? Whenever I try to alter it from my render function, it is undefined, even when I assign 'object' to a global variable, (i.e. 'myMesh').

Comment: @Jackalope You can modify the variable "material" as you like thereafter and the object will change accordingly.

Comment: @IsilmëO. The loader works async and the main code does no wait with the loader. If you want to update the object just after the load it you will get 'null' exception.

Answer (score 12):

Using @WestLangley's answer, I kept getting the error

```
loader.addEventListener is not a function
```

and my page would not load. According to Atul_Mourya at [discourse.threejs.org](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/why-loader-addeventlistener-is-not-a-function/2607), it is a better (or more up-to-date?) idea to implement the function inside of a callback while loading. I combined his advice with the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/OBJLoader.setMaterials) and @WestLangley's [helpful function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16200891/2846766) answering this same question to come up with:

```
var ship_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x444444 } );
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load( 'ship.obj',
    function( obj ){
        obj.traverse( function( child ) {
            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                child.material = ship_material;
            }
        } );
        scene.add( obj );
    },
    function( xhr ){
        console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + "% loaded")
    },
    function( err ){
        console.error( "Error loading 'ship.obj'")
    }
);
```

This example also implements callbacks for progress and error, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used SketchUp to produce my model. When I export from SketchUp to `OBJ` file format the resulting zip includes a `MTL` file;

This code will load both the `MTL` file  and the `OBJ` file; when you `scene.add(object)` after the successful load, the textures are automatically rendered (no need to assign to `child.material.map`)

```
const loader = new OBJLoader(manager);

const materialsLoader = new MTLLoader(manager);

materialsLoader.load('models/obj/sketchup_export/d2e8bc61-6dd1-4554-b874-13b5364d656e.mtl', function (materialsCreator) {

    // https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/OBJLoader.setMaterials
    loader.setMaterials(materialsCreator);


    loader.load('models/obj/sketchup_export/d2e8bc61-6dd1-4554-b874-13b5364d656e.obj', function (obj) {

        object = obj;

    }, onProgress, onError);

}, onProgress, onError);
```