# three.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'center' of undefined

Tags: three.js

I am trying import OBJ (tried different) on server with node.js and three.js - I got this Error after parse file.
This is current code how I import geometry:

```
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    loader.load(modelPath, function (geometryObj) {
    var materialObj = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, overdraw: 0.5 } );
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometryObj, materialObj);
    scene.add(mesh);
```

Here is call stack:

```
this.center.copy( sphere.center );
TypeError: Cannot read property 'center' of undefined
at THREE.Sphere.copy (eval at <anonymous> (/lib/three.js:32:3), <anonymous>:6074:27)
at THREE.Frustum.intersectsObject (eval at <anonymous> (/lib/three.js:32:3), <anonymous>:6253:11)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/lib/three.js:32:3), <anonymous>:36578:53)
at THREE.Object3D.traverseVisible (eval at <anonymous> (/lib/three.js:32:3), <anonymous>:7943:3)
at THREE.Object3D.traverseVisible (eval at <anonymous> (/lib/three.js:32:3), <anonymous>:7947:23)
at projectScene (eval at <anonymous> (/lib/three.js:32:3), <anonymous>:36568:9)
at render (eval at <anonymous> (/lib/three.js:32:3), <anonymous>:35449:28)
```

I know that this was known issue https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/3748 , but I cannot figured out how to fix this error.

Comment: Is the model loaded without using material? If not then is something wrong with your model code

Comment: @mrapsogos Model is just geometry (http://pastebin.com/6gAkVmE0) generate by 3dsmax so it should be ok.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've got the same problem since I discovered that objects loaded by OBJLoader are already a THREE.Mesh instance.

So you should probably do that :

```js
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load(modelPath, function(object) {

    // if you want to add your custom material
    var materialObj = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
        overdraw: 0.5
    });
    object.traverse(function(child) {
        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            child.material = materialObj;
        }
    });

    // then directly add the object
    scene.add(object);
});
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200082/assigning-materials-to-an-objloader-model-in-three-js) and [this example on the three.js website](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_obj).