# TypeError: Cannot read property 'center' of undefined (Three.js + React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I'm having trouble with this error that is the following:

[image]

I'm trying to load an .OBJ file in my react-app and I'm having this error. I've tried to use *object.traverse* like one similar question and nothing. I'll leave my code here:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
const THREE = require('three');
const OBJLoader = require('three-obj-loader');
OBJLoader(THREE);

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    loader.load('/3d/obj.OBJ', verLoad);

    function verLoad(geometry, materials) {

      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
      scene.add(mesh);
      mesh.position.z = -10;

    }

    camera.position.z = 5;

    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    animate();

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [three.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'center' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039553/three-js-typeerror-cannot-read-property-center-of-undefined)

Comment: I've tried the code for the answer to that question, didn't work @Andreas

Comment: you are passing an instance of `THREE.Mesh` as the first argument in another's `THREE.Mesh` constructor. `THREE.Mesh` does not work like that, it takes `THREE.Geometry` as it's first argument.

Comment: The short answer is: you probably switched the Mesh and Geometry parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [OBJLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/OBJLoader) docs the success callback in the `load` method already accepts a `THREE.Mesh` object, so there's no need to create one. Try the following version of your `verLoad` function:

```
function verLoad(obj) {
    obj.position.z = -10;
    scene.add(obj);
}
```

Comment: @soalribeiro How can this be the answer if it is exactly the same method as in the duplicate for which you have specified that it does not work (_"I've tried the code for the answer to that question, **didn't work**"_)? O.o

Comment: I couldnt agree more with the O.o

Comment: In the other question, what solved the problem was `object.traverse`. In my case, it didn't work, but this code worked. I simply took off the line where I create the mesh ` var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);`. In the other question I didn't understood that was the problem. If this answer solved my problem, what's the deal?