# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'center' of undefined from three.module.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I've been coding for a few months now and trying to learn more of three.js/react. I'm currently following a tutorial from [https://redstapler.co/three-js-realistic-rain-tutorial/] where I'm creating a realistic rain background. The tutorial is great and everything was going so far so good until I got to implementing the rain.

In the tutorial, he uses

```js
 rainGeo = new THREE.Geometry();
      for(let i=0;i<rainCount;i++) {
        rainDrop = new THREE.Vector3(
          Math.random() * 400 -200,
          Math.random() * 500 - 250,
          Math.random() * 400 - 200
        );
        rainDrop.velocity = {};
        rainDrop.velocity = 0;
        rainGeo.vertices.push(rainDrop);
      }
      rainMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
        color: 0xaaaaaa,
        size: 0.1,
        transparent: true
      });
      rain = new THREE.Points(rainGeo,rainMaterial);
      scene.add(rain);
```

I was getting an error that Geometry was not exported from Three.js on line 1. So I found out that it was switched to BufferGeometry. I switched it to new THREE.BufferGeometry(); which seemed to get rid of the previous error. However, now I'm getting the new error of  **Cannot read property 'center' of undefined in node_modules/three/build/three.module.js:4534**

I just don't know where to go from here. What I currently have is:

```js
    this.rainCount = 15000
    this.rainGeo = []
    this.geoR = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    for( let i=0; i< this.rainCount; i++) {
      this.rainGeo.push(
        new THREE.Vector3(
          Math.random() * 400 - 200,
          Math.random() * 400 - 250,
          Math.random() * 400 - 200
        )
        ) 
    };

    this.rainMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
      color: 0xaaaaaa,
      size: 0.1,
      transparent: true
    })
    this.rain = new THREE.Points(this.rainGeo, this.rainMaterial);
    this.scene.add(this.rain)
```

`

`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [three.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'center' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039553/three-js-typeerror-cannot-read-property-center-of-undefined)

Comment: I don't think so, because I'm just trying to push vertices onto a BufferGeometry object, where as this question is referring to objLoader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you are creating an instance of `THREE.Points` with an array of `Vector3`s as first argument. This is wrong since an instance of `BufferGeometry` is expected. Try this:

```js
const count = 15000;
const points = [];

for(let i=0; i< count; i++) {
    points.push(
        new THREE.Vector3(
          Math.random() * 400 - 200,
          Math.random() * 400 - 250,
          Math.random() * 400 - 200
        )
    ) 
};

this.geoR = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);

this.rainMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    color: 0xaaaaaa,
    size: 0.1,
    transparent: true
});

this.rain = new THREE.Points(this.geoR, this.rainMaterial);
this.scene.add(this.rain)
```

Comment: Amazing! This worked! Thank you so much! This makes so much more sense.